# Shorthand to specify that a derived class implements all abstract methods?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, syntactic-sugar

I find that in some of my code which relies heavily on C++'s polymorphism features, I have a lot of repetitive method declarations.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void Foo () = 0;
    virtual void Bar () = 0;
};
struct DerivedA : public Base
{
    void Foo () override;
    void Bar () override;
};
struct DerivedB : public Base 
{
    void Foo () override;
    void Bar () override;
};
```

With a greater number of derived classes like DerivedA and DerivedB, and/or more numerous abstract methods than just Foo and Bar, writing the function signatures in each derived class gets really redundant, and to cut down on entirely repeated code I've started using some macros for convenience but this is probably not a great habit.

My question: Is there any keyword or other syntax feature that I can use in each derived class, that essentially informs the compiler "all abstract methods are overridden for this", instead of typing out all of those methods' signatures?

Concept:

```
struct DerivedA : public Base 
{
    concrete;
    // ^ Compiler now allows me to instantiate DerivedA and the linker expects
    // DerivedA::Foo () and DerivedA::Bar() implementations to exist, just as if
    // I had listed every pure virtual function as being overridden explicitly.
};
```

If this does not exist in C++, out of curiosity are there other languages that have this kind of mechanism, and are there any obvious pitfalls w/ this idea?

Comment: My first instinct is **no** and even if it is available I'd avoid it.

C++ (and many languages like it) are built on the idea that _explicit_ is best. This means "hiding" important code like virtual overrides or constructors is dangerous. If you are copying the contents of the overridden functions a lot, I'd suggest putting sensible defaults in the base virtual functions rather than having them be pure virtual.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing like this in standard C++.

Comment: @TomEichlersmith Fair enough, although in my case the code varies significantly between derived classes and having the base class's methods not `= 0` is more dangerous. As it is now, if I forget an override, the code won't compile, whereas with some default code, if I forget to override then it will compile and only have problems at runtime. My specific context: `Base` is Value objects in a dynamically-typed language's interpreter, and `Derived` are different types with `Foo`/`Bar` being things like `ToString`, `IsTruthy`, etc.